# Pandas splitting string into two columns, but the second one doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm scraping tweets and saving them with pandas. One string isn't saving right. This is my code:

```
    for item in client.dataset(run["defaultDatasetId"]).iterate_items():
        tweet_df = pd.DataFrame()

        #TWEET STRING + RETWEET
        tweet_df['Date'] = [item['created_at'][0:19]]
        if item['is_retweet'] == True:
            tweet_df['Retweet'] = ["True"]
        else:
            tweet_df['Retweet'] = ["False"]
        tweet_df['Tweet'] = item['full_text']
```

The string which isn't saving correctly is:
"The Starship team is go for prop load; team is keeping an eye on the weather

I am saving the dataframe and looking at it on a csv:

```
column D                                        column E
Tweet                                       |
________________________________________________________________________
The Starship team is go for prop load       | team is keeping an eye on the weather
```

The csv column has no title and doesn't exist in the dataframe. There are several strings where this is happening, but 90%+ of them are saving fine.

I have tried a regular pandas save.

Comment: Is the core issue that `;` is being interpreted as a column separator?

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: rather than a pandas issue, looking at your code, is it an issue with how `client.dataset(run["defaultDatasetId"])` is parsing your data?  Perhaps that method accepts a specifier for delimiters.

Comment: @JonSG Yeah, pandas interpreting it as separator. Thank you

Comment: @JohnLangham, can you share a reproducible example *as text* and that triggers the issue ?